# Track File Usage in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'm looking for a utlity to track what files are being accessed on a given drive. I've got a drive of files that are accessed by other users, but trying to determine what to delete is difficult as I have to poll the users.

An ideal utility would show:

- How many times the file has been accessed
- The last time the file was accessed or all dates the file was accessed
- Who accessed the file or what process accessed the file
- How long the file was accessed for - on average

This will be run on Windows 7 Professional and ideally would run as a low-priority process.

Bonus points if the utility provides any remote access for monitoring via http.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending upon the type of data you need you might consider using [Disk Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646) utility from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) toolset to log all hard drive manipulations.

If you want to collect more data, than you can use another tool, [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). It monitors the process events, but you can flexibly configure it to monitor only file system activity for given files.

Comment: How would one use this? I download the program. I am trying to track the C:\Program Files (x86)\Wondershare\WAF\2.3.2.219\WsAppService.exe file. I assume I installed it with another program, but it's consuming all of my RAM and I have to manually stop it every time. It has not process, it only is found in Taskmgr -> Resource Monitor -> Memory